# problems sending email in C# MVC by sendinblue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, csharpcodeprovider, sendinblue

I'm trying to email the sendinblue documentation. The application returns the shipping ID, but it does not arrive in the recipient's inbox.

Comment: Hello lemuel2,  Please add some detail to your post. What have you try so far. Check the SMTP setting, junk mail, Mail Server Filter,  Add any error message if any.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.